# Какая спецификация ECMAScript актуальна на данный момент?

Tags: javascript

В тесте попался такой вопрос. Ответил 5.1 - исходил из того, что все браузеры её используют с фичами 6.1. Насколько мне известно, чтобы писать на 6.1 нужно использовать всякие бэйбелы и им подобные. Так и не понял, правильно ли я ответил или нет. Кто-нибудь может подсказать, какая же версия всё-таки актуальна на данный момент? Или этот вопрос изначально некорректен - обе версии актуальны?

Comment: Спецификация JS есть в открытом доступе и если она принята следовательно она актуально, как же происходит принятие нового стандарта? (вкратце). Есть таблица предложений, куда каждый разработчик может написать свое решение с полным описанием и профитом для комьюнити, после этого его предложение рассматривается (что то типо комиссии), далее если есть профит, просматривается возможность реализации в современных основных браузерах, если тут все ок, Только тогда решается включить данную функцию в стандарт. Так что если стандарт принят, он актуален! Вот какой то шаг только упустил, не помню какой...

Comment: @Oma, про осла забыли, тут стандарт бессилен :)

Comment: @Other, Не надо наговаривать тут :-) EDGE вполне ничего :-)

Comment: @Grundy, в сравнении с IE8 - возможно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Текущая законченная спецификация

[ECMA-262

7ᵗʰ Edition / June 2016

ECMAScript® 2016 Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/)

Черновик спецификации можно увидеть на гитхабе: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/

---

Отсюда следует вопрос: что считать *актуальной* версией?

Ответов на этот вопрос может быть несколько:

1. Версия спецификации, обсуждение по которой завершено
2. Самая последняя доступная версия
3. Наиболее поддерживаемая браузерами

Если судить по поддерживаемости браузерами, то даже шестая версия стандарта полностью не поддерживается нигде. В основном за счет части посвященной [модулям](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-modules) и оптимизации хвостовой рекурсии.

С другой стороны, если проверить поддерживаемость, то

- [ES6](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) поддерживается основными браузерами на уровне 95%+ реализации.
- [ES 2016](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/) здесь немного хуже ситуация, реализация на уровне 70%

Трудность разделения заключается так же в том, что браузеры не обязаны реализовать полностью одну версию стандарта, чтобы приступить к реализации следующей. Из-за этого получается, что *все* версии спецификаций могут быть реализованы не полностью и код работающий в одном браузере может не работать в другом.

Исходя из этого можно предположить, что *актуальная* версия - 5, либо шестая версия спецификации, как наиболее поддерживаемая на данный момент (март 2017).

Comment: Стоит ли актуализировать этот ответ?

Comment: @aepot, ссылка на черновик ведет на актуальную версию, в остальном не совсем понятно что именно актуализировать

Comment: За 4 года ничего не поменялось? Например ослик на пенсию пошёл.

Comment: @aepot, не вижу упоминаний IE в ответе.

Comment: Я к тому что за счет этого можно забыть про ES5.